# How to detect UIInterfaceOrientation immediately when device change Orientation (Portrait,Landscape)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uiinterfaceorientation

I create UITableViewCell and i want to change button position when user change landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape  i try to check same this code  but it not auto detect.

```
    - CellForRowAtIndexPath
{
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [Button setFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 50, 20, 50, 50)];
    }else
    {
        [Button setFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 70, 20, 50, 50)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add these to your viewController:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // will rotate
}
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // will animate rotation
}
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    // done rotating
}
```

Or, you can register for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self];
```

Comment: it very helpful i use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:  but  i must set [self.tableview reloaddata] in this method for change position

Comment: Note the difference between device orientation and interface orientation